%%R library("ChemmineR") on colab
On colab I have always used the following code:
!conda install bioconda::bioconductor-chemminer
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
%%R
library("ChemmineR")
It worked, but now I obtain an error:
R[write to console]: Error in library("ChemmineR") : there is no package called ‘ChemmineR’
Error in library("ChemmineR") : there is no package called ‘ChemmineR’
Someone knows how to fix it? Thank you
I would like use ChemmineR on colab

Could you provide System, OS version, and Conda version? Also, are all statement in the same cell? I thin %%R should be at the start of a separate cell.

Could you provide System, OS version, and Conda version? Also, are all statement in the same cell? I thin %%R should be at the start of a separate cell.
